# How can I deploy an existing local site to Pantheon?

Tags: deployment

I have an existing local site that I've developed. In most "normal" instances, I would simply FTP the everything to the external host server, upload and install the database, and life would be good.

With Pantheon, it is frustratingly restricted. There appears to be no control over defining where Apache is configured to serve from. There are restrictions over file structure. And we can not SSH onto the server.

Pantheon appears to be a popular choice - but it appears that there is an assumption that a developer initiates the Drupal instance from Pantheon with all of its inherent configurations

Any experience actually creating a new instance of Drupal on Pantheon from an existing local environment?

BTW - their answer is to use [`drush ard`](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/core/archive-dump/) to "archive the site".. unfortunately, `ard` is no longer supported (Drush 9.x).

Comment: install drupal on pantheon, FTP your ALL directory to pantheon, export DB from patheon UI, in mysql open DB, import there your local DB, export DB, import DB in pantheon UI, done

Comment: Tried that... got nothing but a white screen and no way to debug it. That seems to be the only hope of getting it to work though

Comment: Pantheon has a very specific way the codebase has to be structured. They also run on nginx, so, you get no apache features (like .htaccess). Consult their docs to understand what you need to do. I have one project deploying to Pantheon from a CI service. Once the code is there, upload a database or copy a database in their UI.

Comment: https://pantheon.io/docs/migrate-manual

Comment: Also it seems you have to push code to the master branch on Pantheon to see it appear. I lost a day on that alone.

Comment: Thank you. @kevin That may be the nail in the coffin for Pantheon. I've got a site that I'm building out from a custom (and highly modified) distribution. One day, I will unravel all those dependencies. But for now, I'm stuck with it. And the problem that the distribution is a non-drupal standard. Not sure if I can get around that one or not.

Comment: Acquia > Platform.sh > Self-managed > Pantheon. Just my experience over the last decade or so.

Comment: Have you tried using Lando? I remember seeing somewhere that Lando has a nice integration with Pantheon, so it may be possible to perform the code-swap under Lando, then try using the Pantheon integration to push it into the server. This link may help: https://docs.lando.dev/config/pantheon.html#working-with-multidev